# Can I kill off squadmates?

Tags: mass-effect-3

James really annoys me. I think I'd like him more if he died heroically. It doesn't even have to be heroic, really. Any death will do. Bullets, knives, fire, plague, chin-up bar accident, EDI "accidentally" opening an airlock on him... whatever. *Mass Effect 1* had a few characters that could be killed off (Wrex, Ashley/ Kaiden), and *Mass Effect 2* had a way to kill off almost every NPC party member, though not until late in the game.

[image]

Is there a way I can kill James off in this game? If so, what's the fastest way I can do this?

Comment: A little sadistic, no?  Why not settle for the next best thing and not talk to him or take him on any missions?

Comment: Also, I wonder what that says about Freddy Prince Jr.?

Comment: @MBraedley The desire to kill him rose sharply after the first time I had to have dialog with him while he was doing pull-ups. It was just awkward.

Comment: Maybe he's why some people have been giving ME3 a score of 0.

Comment: James is crying on the inside :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only two squadmates can really die in Mass Effect 3 — and only because of in-game choices you make along the way. James isn't one of them.

The two squadmates that can die are:

> - [Tali](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Tali%27Zorah_nar_Rayya#Mass_Effect_3): she will commit suicide if you side with the Geth
> - [Ashley or Kaidan](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Ashley#Mass_Effect_3) (whichever survived ME1): your squad will shoot them if you can't talk them down at the [part where you kill Udina](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Donnel_Udina#Mass_Effect_3).

Answer (score 1):

**!!!!!!!MAJOR SPOILERS IN LINK!!!!!!!**

[This](http://www.gamespot.com/mass-effect-3/forum/a-list-of-the-characters-who-die-in-me3-spoilers-62190377/) link has a list of characters that can die in ME3, I am not sure if this list it 100% finished or accurate, but I fear James never even makes an appearance on the page. You may be stuck with him eternally.

Answer (score -3):

try resetting all his skills equipping him with the weakest weapons as possible and repeatedly sending him directly into enemy fire (it at least makes me happier)

Comment: Dying in combat and dying "for reals" aren't the same thing in ME.

Comment: As in 90% of RPGs, in fact.