# Are there any good reasons to let a character die?

Tags: mass-effect-3

This question or answers to it will likely contain spoilers.

In the series so far there have been a lot of allies who may have been killed.  In general, it is usually better to help your allies to live and meet whatever criteria are required to ensure you have as many allies as possible.

As I started my game I wondered:  ***Are there any reasons to prefer specific characters dead?***  I mean the first thought that comes to mind is someone gets possessed by a reaper later and makes a boss fight ridiculously hard, or someone turns on you for some other reason.  In addition to allies, are there any NPCs who your actions may have saved in previous games, that might have been better off dead?

Comment: This question lists a pretty specific benefit to having someone die.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53746/can-i-kill-off-squadmates

Comment: Funny...  I saw that one.  I'm referring to practical reasons (i.e. reasons other than the "Jar-Jar Clause".

Comment: Depends.  How nice is their stereo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a very specific benefit for killing off Wrex in the first game:

It is described in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53909/3917).

> The only way to Mordin alive is if Wrex is dead and you did not do Mordin's loyalty quest in ME2.  You can then convince him to deliver the fake cure for the Genophage.

Another very minor point:

You have to kill off Morinth (if she counts as a party member) if you want Samara to be in ME3, as Morinth does not show up in ME3 at all.

Comment: Point of note, Morinth *does* return in ME3 -- as a Banshee.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people killed off characters so they wouldn't have to deal with them later.

Personally, I couldn't stand Kaiden or Ashley in Mass Effect 1, but Kaiden was more annoying so I left him on Virmire. Now Ashley is trying to get with my Shepard after calling him out on Horizon.

So, on my next playthrough, I'll definitely save Kaiden.

On a more serious note, most characters don't tend to have a significant role whether or not they survive.  For example, if you killed Wrex in the first game, he is simply replaced by Wreave.

In the 3rd game, one of the two will be at the emergency species council meeting.

Comment: And Wreav is significantly reasonable than Wrex. Which is one of the reasons Mordin can be convinced if Wrex is dead.

Comment: But Wreav states that after the events of Mass Effect 3, the Krogan will seek revenge on the galaxy. Probably the Turian and Salarians first.