# Is it possible to finish ME3 with only two squad members?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Depending on choices from ME1, ME2, ME3, is it possible to have only two remaining squad members to select from for the final ME3 mission?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's not. I'm pretty sure only Ashley, Kaiden, Tali and Garrus can die. I'm pretty sure it's impossible for Javik, EDI, Liara or James to die.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everyone wants to kill James though...

Comment: @Brandon: [Link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53746/1351) for effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, even without DLC.  Hidden for possible spoilers:

> You can avoid adding the Virmire survivor to your party, and it's possible for Garrus and Tali to die in ME2 (and Tali can die in ME3 as well), but I don't think there is any way to get rid of Liara, James, and EDI.  You should always have at least those three.

Comment: Ah, I forget about the synthetic when thinking about this in my head.