# When given a choice of which squad mate to send to perform a task, is there a risk?

Tags: mass-effect-3

It looks to me that, when I am presented with a choice between two squad mates to perform some task, the primary decision factoring in here is that I won't have their weapons and abilities available for the upcoming wave/waves.

[image: Choose!]

Is this an accurate interpretation, or are there other effects that come into play?  Eg Could one be faster than the other, or is there some task that could fail if you didn't bring a particular squad mate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No,

There are no suicide missions when choosing a squad mate to do a task. You should just pick the squad mate who you could get along without for a couple waves of foes.

Some squad mates complain they will suck at a particular task, in this case James, but I haven't noticed any difference in completion time between the choices.

Comment: [James complaining](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cMfUt3c5qw)

Comment: Pretty sure that if there were suicide missions, [James](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53746/can-i-kill-off-squadmates) would get the nod every time.

Comment: @Brandon: You can't make that comment without [linking to the question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53746/1351).

Comment: @MBraedley I did. His name is linked. :)

Comment: @Brandon: Ha, stupid lack of contrast.